# How can I replace a picture in a Page View Controller with a new View?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

At the moment I have this Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create the data model
    _pageTitles = @[@"Over 200 Tips and Tricks", @"Discover Hidden Features", @"Bookmark          Favorite Tip", @"Free Regular Update"];
    _pageImages = @[@"page1.png", @"page2.png", @"page3.png", @"page4.png"];

    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
```

This uses the 4 images Ive got in my supporting files! But I need the function to read a new scene - in other words, how do I program it to replace the images "example: page1.png" for a "View Controller Scene!?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice tutorial [How To Create UIPageViewController Using Storyboard](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/). You basically need to alter your datasource and/or modify your viewControllerAtIndex: method.

If you are only looking for changing the images, you just need to add your own images to the target (drag them into Xcode navigator or File->Add files), probably tick copy images into the project folder, and adjust the names of the images in the array.

If you add your images into Image Assets in Xcode 5 (they must be PNG) by dragging them into image assets screen, you can then ommit the file extension .png and just refer to the image name as seen in the image assets. You should also adjust if the image is retina or non-retina by moving the image into the right place (either 1x or 2x).

To return a different VC for the last page (index 3), you can do something like:

```
- (UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.        
    if (index == 3) {

        SomeSpecialContentViewController *someSpecialContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeSpecialContentViewController"];

        // configure outlets of this VC
        // ...

        return someSpecialContentViewController;

    } else {

        PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];

        // configure outlets of this VC
        // ...

        return pageContentViewController;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ive already done that one! lol, but thanks how will I do that with the sourse?

Comment: Oh, I see the image names now :) So why don't you just add your own images to the target and change the names in the array? As simple as that. Or do you want a completely different scene? Then you would need to adjust the method I mentioned. Expand on what you want and I will edit the answer.

Comment: Yes I want the page view controller to run a new scene "view controller" For instance the Page View controller needs to manage 2 2 levels on 2 different view controllers. Im about to try a (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers direction: and see how that goes. any thoughts on that?

Comment: If you need a different instance of the content viewController with different layout for example, you can prepare such a viewController with its subclass if needed in IB and assign unique identifier. Then based on the index of the page you just instantiate the right VC in some 'if' statement.

Comment: Edited the code to be functional. It really depends on what you wanna do.

Comment: Right now i have only one view controller that functions with the page  view controller, I need 2 view controllers to function with the current page view controller with separate buttons on each UI image?

Comment: Just design your other VC in storyboard, assign a new class for it, add new identifier and use the code above to instantiate, configure and return the other VC in viewControllerAtIndex:.